# Question about probability using a deck of cards

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability

I am working on this question that involves a player having 2 cards in their hand, an Ace of clubs and a King of clubs. Out of the 50 remaining cards, the player will be given another 5 cards at random for a total of 7 in their hand. What is the probability that at least one of the 5 new cards are either an ace or a king?

My problem is that I don't understand how to mathematically apply the "at least" statement. I know that since the player already has an ace and a king in their hand that the probability of getting either an ace or a king on the next draw is 6/50, then it becomes 6/49 for the next if they still fail to draw an ace or a king and so on and so forth. However, I think my logic is flawed and I am stumped as of now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will get there faster if you start with the probability that none of them is an ace or a king.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to how it would be faster?

Comment: It's only one calculation instead of a dozen of alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask it the other way around. What is the probability of not drawing any kings or aces? That is $\frac{44×43×42×41×40}{50×49×48×47×46} = 0.51$.
You seek the probability of this not hapening, or $1 - 0.51 = 0.49$

Comment: So then the probability of it happening ends up being 49 percent? Doesn't that seem too high? Or am I misinterpreting

Comment: yeah I also thought it seemed high, but the math makes sense. I guess 6 cards in a 50 card deck aren't a small chance enough for it to be not that likely, making the chance of drawing one being quite high.

Comment: P(at least one ace or king in 5) = P(1 Ace in 5)+ P(2 Ace in 5) +P(3 Ace in 5)  + P(1 King in 5)+ P(2 king in 5) +P(3 King in 5)

Comment: @SagarM that's a nice way to put it

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the probability that none of the new cards are an ace or a king (pretty straight forward, I think).
The probability you want is 1 minus this probability